# Understanding Akka Dispatcher

Tags: scala, akka

I have couple of questions based on below sample code.

1) I specified

```
akka.cluster.use-dispatcher = cluster-dispatcher in my config.
```

When I put a breakpoint on this line  in Frontend.scala,

```
   _frontend = system.actorOf(Props[Frontend],
        name = "frontend")
```

I see the default-dispatcher inside the "_frontend" object.  How come it didn't get the cluster-dispatcher from the configuration?

2) I want to simulate the blocking scenario this documentation is talking about.
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/dispatchers.html#problem-blocking-on-default-dispatcher
I tried to put the default-dispatcher

```
default-dispatcher {
  fork-join-executor {
    parallelism-min = 1
    parallelism-max = 1
    throughput = 1
  }
}
```

And I thought one "receive" in backend would be processing at one time. First of all, I debug into the "_frontend" object again and I don't think it reads in my default.  Secondly, if you have multiple actors running in different remote processes, what does it mean by all actors share the same default dispatcher and that blocking tasks can cause thread starvation? If the actors are run in different processes, don't think they each have their own pool of threads?  The bottom line is, if you can give me an example or modify below that i can produce the thread starvation scenario, then I can understand what it's talking about better. Thanks for your help.
Grace

```
  akka {
      actor {
        provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
    //    default-dispatcher {
    //      fork-join-executor {
    //        parallelism-min = 1
    //        parallelism-max = 1
    //        throughput = 1
    //      }
    //    }
      }
      remote {
        log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
        netty.tcp {
          hostname = "127.0.0.1"
          port = 0
        }
      }

      akka.cluster.use-dispatcher = cluster-dispatcher

      cluster-dispatcher {
        type = "Dispatcher"
        executor = "fork-join-executor"
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-min = 1
          parallelism-max = 1
        }
      }


      cluster {
        seed-nodes = [
          "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551",
          "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552"]

        auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
      }
    }

    akka.cluster.min-nr-of-members = 3


    akka.cluster.role {
      frontend.min-nr-of-members = 1
      backend.min-nr-of-members = 2
    }

    akka.actor.deployment {
      /frontend/backendRouter {
        # Router type provided by metrics extension.
        router = adaptive-group
        # Router parameter specific for metrics extension.
        # metrics-selector = heap
        # metrics-selector = load
        # metrics-selector = cpu
        metrics-selector = mix
        #
        nr-of-instances = 100
        routees.paths = ["/user/backend"]
        cluster {
          enabled = on
          use-role = backend
          allow-local-routees = off
        }
      }
    }
```

============================

```
package com.packt.akka.loadBalancing

import com.packt.akka.commons.Add

object LoadBalancingApp extends App {

//initiate three nodes from backend
Backend.initiate(2551)

Backend.initiate(2552)

Backend.initiate(2561)

//initiate frontend node
Frontend.initiate()

Thread.sleep(10000)

Frontend.getFrontend ! Add(2, 4)

}
```

=============================

```
package com.packt.akka.loadBalancing

import akka.cluster._
import com.packt.akka.commons._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import akka.cluster.ClusterEvent.MemberUp
import akka.actor.{ Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props, RootActorPath }

class Backend extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case Add(num1, num2) =>
      println(s"I'm a backend with path: ${self} and I received add operation.")
      Thread.sleep(60000)
      println(s"I'm a backend with path: ${self} and I am done with add operation.")
  }

}

object Backend {
  def initiate(port: Int){
    val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(s"akka.remote.netty.tcp.port=$port").
      withFallback(ConfigFactory.parseString("akka.cluster.roles = [backend]")).
      withFallback(ConfigFactory.load("loadbalancer"))

    val system = ActorSystem("ClusterSystem", config)

    val Backend = system.actorOf(Props[Backend], name = "backend")

    Backend
  }
}
```

=====================

```
    package com.packt.akka.loadBalancing

    import com.packt.akka.commons._
    import scala.concurrent.duration._
    import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
    import akka.actor.{ Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props } 
    import akka.cluster.Cluster
    import akka.routing.FromConfig
    import akka.actor.ReceiveTimeout
    import scala.util.Random


    class Frontend extends Actor {
      import context.dispatcher

      val backend = context.actorOf(FromConfig.props(), name = "backendRouter")

      context.system.scheduler.schedule(3.seconds, 3.seconds, self,
        Add(Random.nextInt(100), Random.nextInt(100)))

      def receive = {
        case addOp: Add =>
          println("Frontend: I'll forward add operation to backend node to handle it.")
          backend forward addOp

      }

    }


object Frontend {

  private var _frontend: ActorRef = _ 

  val upToN = 200

  def initiate() = {
    val config = ConfigFactory.parseString("akka.cluster.roles = [frontend]").
      withFallback(ConfigFactory.load("loadbalancer"))

    val system = ActorSystem("ClusterSystem", config)
    system.log.info("Frontend will start when 2 backend members in the cluster.")
    //#registerOnUp
    Cluster(system) registerOnMemberUp {
      _frontend = system.actorOf(Props[Frontend],
        name = "frontend")
    }
    //#registerOnUp

  }

  def getFrontend = _frontend
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) See the documentation of `akka.cluster.use-dispatcher = cluster-dispatcher in my config.` in the [reference.conf](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-cluster/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L147):

```
# The id of the dispatcher to use for cluster actors. If not specified
# default dispatcher is used.
# If specified you need to define the settings of the actual dispatcher.
use-dispatcher
```

This setting allows you to customize what dispatcher is used for 'internal' cluster actors, not for your own actors.

2) The `parallelism-max` parameter to the ForkJoinPool does not limit the number of actual threads. As explained in the [note in the documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/dispatchers.html#looking-up-a-dispatcher):

> Note that the parallelism-max does not set the upper bound on the total number of threads allocated by the ForkJoinPool. It is a setting specifically talking about the number of hot threads the pool keep running in order to reduce the latency of handling a new incoming task. You can read more about parallelism in the JDK’s [ForkJoinPool documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html).

You are correct that when actors run in different JVM processes, they have separate dispatchers.

If you want to do an experiment and see thread starvation problems in action, the easiest approach is to create an actor that uses blocking calls (for example `Thread.sleep`) in its message processing. Now proceed to create many instances of this actor, and send them messages. You will see your program making very slow progress.

To contrast, if you write that same actor but achieve the 'delayed computation' with a scheduler instead of with a `Thread.sleep`, you should see much better performance.

Comment: Thank you so much.  "This setting allows you to customize what dispatcher is used for 'internal' cluster actors, not for your own actors."  Could you give some examples of 'internal' cluster actors?

Comment: Uh, well, for example an internal actor that listens to the event bus for cluster events, https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/fafc59b19d9b6fb6371c08cc16039caf64bdb05c/akka-cluster/src/main/scala/akka/cluster/ClusterReadView.scala#L103

Comment: I see.  Thanks.  In what case would someone customize the cluster-dispatcher and not use the default if it's used by internal actors...?

Comment: To be quite honest I can't really think of a situation where I would recommend that. Perhaps as a workaround when we find a bug in one of the internal actors that would put too much stress on the default dispatcher, then you could move those to a separate dispatcher until the bug is fixed.

Comment: Any way to define custom dispatcher for entity actors(user actors) like use-dispatcher configuration?